# Setup Salesforce rest services on localhost

Tags: c#, salesforce

I want to consume salesforce RESTful services but i am unable to authenticate.what i did.
1) created connected app
2) added consumer key
3) added consumer secrete key
4) added security token
4) Oauth scope to full access
5) callback url set to https://localhost:3081/Default.aspx

I am getting this error:
{  "error_description": "authentication failure",  "error": "invalid_grant"}

My code is

```
private static async void AuthenticateSfdcRestUser()
    {


        HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient();

        //defined remote access app - develop --> remote access --> new


        //set OAuth key and secret variables
        string sfdcConsumerKey = "XXXXX";
        string sfdcConsumerSecret = "XXXXX";

        //set to Force.com user account that has API access enabled
        string sfdcUserName = "XXXXX";
        string sfdcPassword = "XXXXX";
        string sfdcToken = "XXXXX";

        //create login password value
        string loginPassword = sfdcPassword + sfdcToken;

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"grant_type","password"},
                {"client_id",sfdcConsumerKey},
                {"client_secret",sfdcConsumerSecret},
                {"username",sfdcUserName},
                {"password",loginPassword}
            }
             );

        HttpResponseMessage message = await authClient.PostAsync("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", content);

        string responseString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(responseString);
        oauthToken = (string)obj["access_token"];
        serviceUrl = (string)obj["instance_url"];

        //print response values
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The token value is {0}", responseString));
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to continue ...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: try changing this `"https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"` to the following 
`"https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"`

Comment: i am unable to login to "https://test.salesforce.com".
is there anything wrong with callback url ?    @MethodMan